# How to get file name and mime type before upload in ionic2?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, file-upload, ionic-native

I am trying to upload files by using help of ionic/file-chooser plugin. Everything was perfect until i did not get requirement to upload a doc or pdf file.
I am using ionic 3.12.0 and cordova 7.0.1.

```
 const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'files0',
      fileName: 'name.jpg',
      params: {
        Authkey: this.CS.auth_key,
        Token: this.CS.token,
        group_id: this.CS.activeGroupId,
        Userid: this.CS.userId
      }
    };
    this.fileChooser.open()
      .then(uri => {
        this.CS.show_loader();
        //alert(uri );
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri)
          .then((files)=> {
          alert(JSON.stringify(files, null, 4));
        }).catch((err) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
        });
        //let name = uri.split("/");
        //options.fileName = name[name.length - 1];
       // alert(options.fileName);
        fileTransfer.upload(uri, this.CS.base_url + 'groups/uploadChat', options)
          .then((data) => {
            this.CS.hide_loader();
            this.res = data;
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            let d = JSON.parse(this.res.response);

            if(d.status == 1){
              let a = {
                member_id: this.user_id,
                imageLink: this.groupChatData.loginUserData.imageLink,
                message: '',
                attachment: d.data[0].attachment,
                member_name: this.CS.userData.name,
                mime_type: d.data[0].mime_type,
                attachment_imageUrl: d.data[0].attachment_imageUrl,
                attachment_linkUrl: d.data[0].attachment_linkUrl,
                send_at: Date.now()
              };
              this.group_chat.push(a);
              setTimeout(() => this.content.scrollToBottom(), 200);
            }else{
              this.CS.alertMessage("error", this.res.response.message);
            }

          }, (err) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
          })
      })
      .catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4)));
```

the resolveLocalFilesystemUrl return something like this -

[image]

There are neither file name nor file type, then how can i send file name to server?

Answer (score 7):

### First Solution

To get the file name and file mime, try the following:

First you need to install the following plugins:

1. [`fileChooser`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/)
2. [`filePath`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/)
3. [`file`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

then you can do the following:

```
  this.fileChooser.open().then(uri =>
    {
      console.log(uri);
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(filePath =>
        {
          this.filesPath = filePath;
          this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath).then(fileInfo =>
            {
              let files = fileInfo as FileEntry;
              files.file(success =>
                {
                  this.fileType   = success.type;
                  this.filesName  = success.name;
                });
            },err =>
            {
              console.log(err);
              throw err;
            });
        },err =>
        {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        });
    },err =>
    {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
```

This works on android, the `fileChooser.open()` plugin will open the file system so you can choose a file, the `filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)` will give you the path of the file.

The method `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath)` will give you information about the file as you have shown in the question. It also return a Promise of type `Entry`, which does not contain the name and the type.

Therefore you need to use the `as` keyword to cast it to type [`FileEntry`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/www/FileEntry.js#L80) that will contain both the `name` and the `type`.

---

### Second Solution

```
  fileUpload()
 {
 this.arrayType = ["txt", "pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "gif", "csv"];
if(this.platform.is("ios"))
{
  this.filePicker.pickFile().then(uri=>
  {
    console.log(uri);
    this.filesPath  = uri;
    this.fileName   = filesPath.substring(filesPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    this.fileType   = this.fileName.substring(this.fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  },err=>
  {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  });
}
else if(this.platform.is("android"))
{
  this.fileChooser.open().then(uri =>
  {
    console.log(uri);
    this.paths = uri;
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(filePath =>
    {
      console.log(filePath);
      this.filesPath  = filePath;
      this.fileName   = filesPath.substring(filesPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      this.fileType   = this.fileName.substring(this.fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
      if(this.arrayType.indexOf(this.fileType) > -1)
      {
       console.log("accepted type");
      }
    },err=>
    {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
  },err=>
  {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  });
  }
}
```

This solution is for both ios and android, here first you check which platform the user is using, then using the [`filepicker`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ios-file-picker/) plugin, you can retrieve the file and using `subString` you can get the name and the type. Regarding android, you can use `resolveNativePath(uri)` method of the `filePath` plugin to get the path of the file and then using `subString` you can get the name and type.

You can also check if the type of the file is in the array of types or not.

Comment: Clear and pleasant